# Parsing content in html tags using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to parse content from

```
<td>content</td>
and
<td *?*>content</td>
and 
<td *specific td class*>content</td>
```

How can i make this with regex, php and preg match?

Comment: I think maybe we've reached the stage where language specific sites for so are necessary...

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) sums it up pretty good.

In short, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Instead, look at the DOM classes and especially [DOMDocument::loadHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Answer (score 3):

If you have an HTML document, you really shouldn't use regular expressions to parse it : HTML is just not "regular" enough for that.

A far better solution would be to load your HTML document using a DOM parser -- for instance, [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and [Xpath queries](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) often do a really great job !

Comment: seconded... regex is the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>content</td>`: `<td>([^<]*)</td>`

`<td *specific td class*>content</td>`: `<td[^>]*class=\"specific_class\"[^>]*>([^<]*)<`

Answer (score 0):

@OP, here's one way

```
$str = <<<A
<td>content</td>
<td *?*>content</td>
<td *specific td class*>content</td>
<td *?*> multiline
content </td>
A;

$s = explode("</td>",$str);
foreach ($s as $a=>$b){
    $b=preg_replace("/.*<td.*>/","",$b);
    print $b."\n";
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
content

content

content

 multiline
content
```